# BEGIN,INSERT,COMMIT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1- beoordelingen

2 - sterren

I need to **update** 3 values in **table beoordelingen** and **insert** new values into **table sterren**

How do I do that?

ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't work and I can't find anywhere how to do it.

```
$sql=$dbo->prepare("BEGIN;INSERT INTO   beoordelingen(beoordelingid,userid,werkid,inlijn,
sjabloon,conclusie,save)

VALUES ('$beoordelingid','$user','$werkid','$inlijn','$sjabloon','$conclusie','0')

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
beoordelingid=VALUES(beoordelingid),userid=VALUES(userid), werkid=VALUES(werkid),
inlijn=VALUES(inlijn),sjabloon=VALUES(sjabloon),conclusie=VALUES(conclusie),
save=VALUES(save);

INSERT INTO sterren (beoordelingid,userid,werkid,titelwerk,actie,sterren)

VALUES ('$beoordelingid','$user','$id','$titelwerk',
'$actie','$sterren'); COMMIT");
```

I adapted the following. The insert1 still won't work. Insert2 works

```
$dbo->beginTransaction();

//NOT WORKING
$insert1 = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO beoordelingen(beoordelingid, userid, werkid, inlijn, sjabloon, conclusie, save)
VALUES (:beoordelingid, :user, :werkid, :inlijn, :sjabloon, :conclusie, '0')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
beoordelingid=VALUES(beoordelingid),
userid=VALUES(userid),
werkid=VALUES(werkid),
inlijn=VALUES(inlijn),
sjabloon=VALUES(sjabloon),
conclusie=VALUES(conclusie),
save=VALUES(save);"
);
//THIS WORKS
$insert2 = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO sterren (beoordelingid, userid, werkid, titelwerk, actie, sterren)
VALUES (:beoordelingid, :user, :id, :titelwerk, :actie, :sterren);"
);
//NOT WORKING
$insert1->execute(array(
'beoordelingid' => $beoordelingid,
'user' => $user,
'werkid' => $werkid,
'inlijn' => $inlijn,
'sjabloon' => $sjabloon,
'conclusie' => $conclusie,
'save' => $save
));
//THIS WORKS
$insert2->execute(array(
'beoordelingid' => $beoordelingid,
'user' => $user,
'id' => $werkid,
'titelwerk' => $titelwerk,
'actie' => $actie,
'sterren' => $sterren
));

$dbo->commit();
```

My last problem:

```
$sterren=$_POST['sterren'];
$user=$_REQUEST['user'];
$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$actie=$_POST['actie'];

$dbo->beginTransaction();
//THIS WORKS
$insert1 = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO  sterren(sterren,userid,actie)
VALUES (:sterren, :userid, :actie);"
);

//THIS DOESN"T WORK
$insert2 = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO sterren(sterren,userid,actie)
VALUES (:-sterren, :user, :actie);"
);

//THIS WORKS
$insert1->execute(array(
'sterren' => $sterren,
'userid' => $userid,
'actie' => $actie
 ));

//THIS DOESN"T WORK
$insert2->execute(array(
'-sterren' => $sterren,
'user' => $user,
'actie' => $actie
));

$dbo->commit();
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can only `prepare()` *one* SQL query at a time.  I don't think you can run multiple SQL queries at the same time like that (security reasons).  Also, unless `$beoordelingid` (and every other variable you are concatenating into that string) is a `?`, then you are misusing prepared statements and are still completely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: P.S. Is this PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: It's PDO. The BEGIN,INSERT,COMMIT works without the ON UPDATE DUPLICATE KEY to insert into two tables, and it also works without the BEGIN,INSERT,COMMIT to update the table beoordelingen.  But I need to do both...

Comment: Which field is the "key" in the `beoordelingen` table? Are you sure you want `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update *all* the fields?  Do you see any errors?  Try this: `var_dump($insert1->errorInfo());`

Comment: The update key is beoordelingid,

Comment: I get no errors. userid and werkid don't need updating, the rest does

Comment: So, `var_dump($insert1->errorInfo());` doesn't show anything?  Have you tried to run the SQL query directly in MySQL?  If `beoordelingid` is the key, then `beoordelingid=VALUES(beoordelingid)` probably isn't needed.  Try removing `beoordelingid=VALUES(beoordelingid)` (and others that you don't need to update).

Comment: Problem solved! It was the save '0'. I changed it into ':save' and now all is working fine! Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh!  Whoops!  That was my fault... I didn't notice that when I wrote the answer.

Comment: that was the wrong one. This is the one;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811220/order-by-one-id-when-there-are-more-of-the-same-ids-in-one-table?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how to use prepared statements (`->prepare()`) or how to use a transaction with PDO.

First off, [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) is for "preparing" *one* SQL query with placeholders so that you can pass the parameters in a later function ([`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)) and avoid SQL injection from concatenating strings.

Second, if you want to use a transaction then you should use PDO's [`beginTransaction`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [`commit`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) functions.

Try something like this:

```
$dbo->beginTransaction();

$insert1 = $dbo->prepare('INSERT INTO beoordelingen(beoordelingid, userid, werkid, inlijn, sjabloon, conclusie, save)
    VALUES (:beoordelingid, :user, :werkid, :inlijn, :sjabloon, :conclusie, :save)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        beoordelingid=VALUES(beoordelingid),
        userid=VALUES(userid),
        werkid=VALUES(werkid),
        inlijn=VALUES(inlijn),
        sjabloon=VALUES(sjabloon),
        conclusie=VALUES(conclusie),
        save=VALUES(save);'
);

$insert2 = $dbo->prepare('INSERT INTO sterren (beoordelingid, userid, werkid, titelwerk, actie, sterren)
    VALUES (:beoordelingid, :user, :id, :titelwerk, :actie, :sterren);'
);

$insert1->execute(array(
    'beoordelingid' => $beoordelingid,
    'user' => $user,
    'werkid' => $werkid,
    'inlijn' => $inlijn,
    'sjabloon' => $sjabloon,
    'conclusie' => $conclusie
));

$insert2->execute(array(
    'beoordelingid' => $beoordelingid,
    'user' => $user,
    'id' => $id,
    'titelwerk' => $titelwerk,
    'actie' => $actie,
    'sterren' => $sterren
));

$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, if you are still around, could you take a look again? I adapted the 2 query's (see above) and query 2 works fine. But whatever I do, query 1 is ignored by the database totally. Thanks

Comment: Hi, How do I insert the last inserted id from query 1 with query 2? (in case it's a different query without update)

Comment: @TimiaBreederveld: You can try [`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php): `$insertID = $dbo->lastInsertId();` (after `$insert1->execute`).

Comment: Hi R.H, I have one last problem and after that I'm all done. I posted the query above. A user is sending something he has (variable values) to another user. Will be added to the other user and substracted from the user. So I need to put in a minus value. Just putting a minus before it doesn't work.  If you could help me (again :-)) I would be very happy. No pressure, only if you have nothing else on your hands....Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "putting a minus before it"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to put a negative value in the database. It works if  use values like this :VALUES ('-$sterren') but not if I use values like above.

Comment: Just do `$sterren = -$sterren;`.

Comment: That would work if I only had to put a negative value, but I also have to add the same in query 1 as a positive value.....

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is then?  Before you call `->execute()`, just set up your variables to hold the values you want.

Comment: Yup, sorry, my mistake, there was another something not working. But all is working fine now! THANKS AGAIN!!!!!!!